# getStorage('block')

Tags: 8

I try to load the body field from a custom block in Drupal 8.

```
$block = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block')->load($block_id);
```

The result in $block is NULL.

A similar code for a node does work:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node_id);
$body = $node->get('body')->value;
```

getStorage should work for all entities, why not for blocks?

What is wrong?

Comment: Presumably your `$block_id` is incorrect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Block is the wrong machine name, that is a placed config entity, you want custom_block or block_content, can't remember which off the top of my head, check the ID in the entity type annotation in block content module

Comment: Oh, I missed the *custom* in there. Right, that's block_content.

Comment: @Berdir has the correct answer, the entity is block_content, this code works: `$block = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block_content')->load('5'); $body = $block->get('body')->value;